# What's the meaning of the regex?

Tags: regex

Can anybody point it out?

1. `/^([a-zA-Z]+)/`
2. `/\d|M|H/`
3. `RegExp.$1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1.

`/^([a-zA-Z]+)/`

```
^             # match the start of the input string
(             # start capture group 1
  [a-zA-Z]+   #   match one or more from the set {a..z,A..Z} 
)             # end capture group 1
```

### 2.

`/\d|M|H/`

```
\d  # match a digit: {0..9}
|   # OR
M   # match the literal 'M'
|   # OR
H   # match the literal 'H'
```

which, as @Tim suggested in the comments, could better be written as: `[\dMH]`

### 3.

`RegExp.$1` is probably not a regex (at least, it can't match anything). It's likely a language construct.

Comment: Just to add, in a Regex you can use $1 to say its the first match for any regex.

Comment: @Sachin, I think you mean `\1`. The `$1` is often used in a replacement-string, not the regex itself. Note that `$` is a special character: it matches the end of the input string.

Comment: @Bart Kiers - yes you are right, Actually I meant $1 used in replacement-string is the first match.

Comment: @Sachin: sure, but note that the OP is talking about regex-patterns, not replacement-strings.

Comment: @Bart Kiers - yes true. Actually not sure what OP is expecting here by asking what does RegExp.$1 means.

Comment: And of course you could write `[\dMH]` instead of `\d|M|H`.

Answer (score 1):

That means:

1. /^([a-zA-Z]+)/ - it must starts with any alphabet
2. /\d|M|H/ - it can be any digits, M or H
3. RegExp.$1 - First argument of the Regex

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *first argument of the regex*, but `RegExp` is the global object that contains all the information about the last regex match, and `RegExp.$1` is the contents of the first capturing group.

Comment: yes, your right, that's first capturing group. thanks man for correction.